# How to link table row heights from two tables in SQL reporting services

Tags: report, row, reportingservices-2005

I have two tables in a SQL Reporting Services report (table + matrix) that I would like to display side by side to give the illusion of one complete table.

The problem is that there may be more data in the row of one table vs the other and therefore the rows could be different heights.

Is there any way to match/link the heights of the rows in both tables.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so after an exhaushtive search I dont think there is an answer to this one.

My proposed work round for this is to export straight to Excel which is what my users will do anyway. Excel lines up all the rows correctly. The only thing to be aware of here is the join between the table and the matrix as sometimes excel will merge two columns together if they overlap.

Comment: did you ever find a way to at least get the height of a table?